# ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

My program keeps showing the following error:

```
ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f3c06e06bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55ef40410382 in newNode ../../src/bst/bst.c:11
    #2 0x55ef404106e0 in Insert ../../src/bst/bst.c:32
    #3 0x55ef40411867 in main ../../src/bst/bst.c:125
    #4 0x7f3c061c10b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

Indirect leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f3c06e06bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55ef40410382 in newNode ../../src/bst/bst.c:11
    #2 0x55ef404106e0 in Insert ../../src/bst/bst.c:32
    #3 0x55ef40410926 in Insert ../../src/bst/bst.c:37
    #4 0x55ef40410926 in Insert ../../src/bst/bst.c:37
    #5 0x55ef40411867 in main ../../src/bst/bst.c:125
    #6 0x7f3c061c10b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 48 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

some of the inputs that cause these errors are:

```
input
-----
i 1
d 1
s 1
i 2
i 3
i 4
d 3
s 2
s 3
s 4
i 1
d 2
s 1
s 2
s 3
s 4
-----

input
-----
d 5
i -84
s 5
i -5
d 0
d -84
s -84
s -5
-----
```

"i" refers to the Insert function
"p" refers to the Print function
"s" refers to the Search function
"d" refers to the Delete function

It mentions a couple of lines that cause these errors but I do not see how I could resolve them.

Line 43: `if (root == NULL || root->key == key)`
Line 73: `free(root);`
Line 11: `struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
Line 32: `return newNode(key);`

This is my source code for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node* newNode(int item)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}


void Print(struct node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("(");
        Print(root->left);
        printf("%d", root->key);
        Print(root->right);
        printf(")");
    }
}

struct node* Insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return newNode(key);

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = Insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = Insert(node->right, key);

    return node;
}
struct node* Search(struct node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL || root->key == key)
        return root;
    
    if (root->key < key)
        return Search(root->right, key);

    return Search(root->left, key);
}
struct node* maxNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;
 
    /* loop down to find the rightmost leaf */
    while (current && current->right != NULL)
        current = current->right;
 
    return current;
}
struct node* Delete(struct node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
 
    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = Delete(root->left, key);
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = Delete(root->right, key);
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
 
    //2 children
    //max in left subtree
        struct node* temp = maxNode(root->left);
        root->key = temp->key;
        root->left = Delete(root->left, temp->key);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    char c;
    int x;
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    if(c != 'p'){
        scanf(" %d",&x);
        if(c == 'i'){
            if(!Search(root, x)){
                root = Insert(root, x);
                printf("inserted");
            }else{ 
                printf("not inserted");
            }
        }else if(c == 's'){
            if(Search(root,x)){
                printf("present");
            }else{
                printf("absent");
            }
        }else if(c == 'd'){
            Delete(root, x);
        }
    }else{
        Print(root);
    }
    
    while(scanf(" %c",&c)!=EOF){
        if(c != 'p'){
            scanf(" %d",&x);
            if(c == 'i'){
                if(!Search(root, x)){
                    root = Insert(root, x);
                    printf("inserted");
                }else{ 
                    printf("not inserted");
                }
            }else if(c == 's'){
                if(Search(root,x)){
                    printf("present");
                }else{
                    printf("absent");
                }
            }else if(c == 'd'){
                Delete(root, x);
            }
        }else{
            Print(root);
        }   
    }
    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please copy the tool output into the question as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please also give the exact input that results in those errors.

Comment: @kaylum I edited the question with the full error and the inputs as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Should be `root = Delete(root, x);` in the main function instead of just `Delete(root, x);`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you! I fixed that part now in my code but the errors for lines 11 and 32 still persist for some reason.

Comment: Those are just happening because you inserted 5 items and deleted only 3. The program concludes you are leaking some memory. A possible fix for this could be to delete the whole tree at the end by recursively walking it and deleting each node.